# Foreach loop - three columns(dynamic) table layout

Tags: php, foreach, html-table

I have the below code,  which will create  a table with three columns.

```
<?php $t = array(' 1 ' , ' 2 ' ,' 3 ', ' 4 ' , ' 5 ');
$count = 0;
$col =3;
echo '<table><tr>';
foreach($t  AS $r){
    $count++;
    echo '<td> '.$r.' </td>';
    if($count == $col){
        echo '</tr><tr>';
        $count = 0;
    }
}
echo '</tr></table>';

?>
```

but what I really want is for the first column to have at least 4 rows before creating a new column and so on. max number of columns is 3 and each column should have at least 4 rows.

Comment: You need to provide a sample (using text is fine) of how you want your data laid out in your table.  Given your variable `$t`, how do you want the table to look? Which cell (row / column) contains the '1'? Which cell contains the '2'? etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start asking how many elements your array has, say:

```
$elementsCount= count($t);
```

Then test to decide how many columns you'll need:

```
if($elementsCount>8){
  $maxCols= 3;
}
elseif($elementsCount>4){
  $maxCols= 2;
}
else{
  $maxCols= 1;
}
```

Now you create three foreach loops, one to each situation.

Whether it would be possible to know if you want or not do distribute elements evenly, it would be possible to solve the problem with just one single loop and not three.